# Visual Studio 2012/TFS 2012 - Configuration system failed to initialize

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've recently uninstalled and re-installed some IBM programs on my computer.  Now when I go to connect to TFS, I get the errror:

TF205020....  Configuration system failed to initialize.

In the end I removed my server from my server list and now when I add it, I get the same thing (without the number).  This leads me to believe that something is messed up in my Visual Studio instance.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and connecting to a TFS 2012 server.

I tried deleting config files under C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Configuration\VersionControl, but that didn't help.

Thanks for anyone with an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this usually happens if you have a broken web.config file. Check to make sure your machine.config files for v2.0 and v4.0 does not have any any broken tags.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't checked the 32 bit Framework folder.  Turns out my DbProviderFactories tag was missing an end tag.

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. My VS was behaving super strangely as well. Would have been better had they just issued a warning that a config file was bad instead of a generic "Packages cannot be loaded" error.